# How to make a Typescript generic extend a certain type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have a component

```
const MyComponent = <T, extends { optionalProperty?: MyType }>
```

and then when calling `<MyComponent<SomeGeneric>>`

but this complains that `Type 'SomeGeneric' has no properties in common with type '{ optionalProperty?: MyType | undefined; }'.`

so to fix it `<MyComponent<SomeGeneric & {optionalProperty: {}}>>` works but I'd rather not do that, since it's optional, why cant I just leave it out?

Comment: Are you trying to add `{ optionalProperty?: MyType }` to `T`? If so, the syntax is `T & { optionalProperty?: MyType }`.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript uses the mathematical *set theory* for type compliances. `A extends B` basically means that `A` is a *subset* of the set `B`. *Subset* is a set that contains some elements of the set, including an empty set and every element. If `A` is a *subset* of `B`, then `B` is a *superset* of `A`. Example:

Imagine `B` to be a set of `{1, 2, 3}`, then it will have the following subsets:

```
{},
{1}, {2}, {3},
{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3},
{1, 2, 3}
```

In Typescript the *superset* is the less specified type, whereas a *subset* is a more specific one:

- `1` is a subset of `number`
- `'str'` is a subset of `string`
- `{a: string}` is a subset of `{a?: string}`

In your case your *superset* is `{optionalProperty?: MyType}` and a valid *subset* for this constraint would be any type that has at least `optionalProperty` in it, no matter if it is optional or not. Example:

```
// true
type Case1 = { optionalProperty?: MyType } extends { optionalProperty?: MyType }
  ? true
  : false;

// true
type Case2 = { optionalProperty: MyType } extends { optionalProperty?: MyType }
  ? true
  : false;

// false
type Case3 = { random: MyType } extends { optionalProperty?: MyType }
  ? true
  : false;

// true
type Case4 = { random: MyType; optionalProperty?: MyType } extends {
  optionalProperty?: MyType;
}
  ? true
  : false;
```

So, even though the property is optional, your generic type still should include that property optionally in itself.

A possible workaround would be to remove the `extends` operator and just expect `T & { optionalProperty?: MyType }` as an argument:

```
const MyComponent = <T>(props: T & { optionalProperty?: MyType }) => null;
```

Testing:

```
MyComponent({ random: '' }); // no error
```